Power harness on interconnected smoke detector
I have two interconnected smoke detectors that are disconnected. The issue is they are 20feet ceilings and I can’t get to it because in the middle of the night I’m getting false alarms. Will place battery ones below where reachable.
Question is can I push the power harness and connector wires back up into the junction box and place a plate over it?

Removing the interconnected-ness may not be allowed, be sure to check your local regulations. Your best bet is to get a tall ladder

I suspect the false alarms are the alarms "running out" of radiation. Replace them and they'll be good for another decade

The smoke detectors work where the smoke is going to be.  Placing them lower would be pointless and dangerous and possibly illegal (depending on where you are).
From experience, they need to be within 18inches of the ceiling.  But there may be local laws covering this.
The solution would be to get interconnected ones with a remote reset.

Remote reset? Which would that be? And I’m  going to place a battery operated one on the wall higher up where i can reach it.

If you are taking down the alarms, remove the harness as well and cap the wires. ( why leave the harness if no alarm) or cover the end of the harness with some electrical tape. ( I still like the idea of removing the harness.)
Then you certainly can cover the box with an approved cover.
